# Why am I receiving http error 403.14 when using ISAPI redirect in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, load-balancing, tomcat5.5, isapi-redirect

I am trying to test using IIS as a load balancer for a Java application running on Tomcat. When I try to load the site in a browser after following the tutorial at [this site](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/load-balancing-tomcat-7-using-iis-7-5/), an IIS error page appears reading "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." I revisited every detail of the tutorial and haven't found any missteps.

The one big variation is that I'm using a Java application with Tomcat 5.5 bundled with it.

I simplified things by narrowing the workers down to the load balancer and one Tomcat instance/AJP worker.

I've consulted other tutorials and the [Apache-provided documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html), which led me to move the isapi_redirect.dll, workers.properties, and uriworkermap.properties files into the Tomcat directories and move the isapi_redirect.properties settings into the registry (and adjust directory paths referenced in properties files and IIS to match). I continue to receive the 403.14 error. When I enable directory listing in IIS, the site loads a listing of the files in the bin directory.

The isapi_redirect log isn't being generated, so I believe the problem is in the IIS or isapi_redirect setup. What might I be missing that would lead to a 403.14 error?

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5, ISAPI_redirect 1.2.35, Tomcat 5.5.